# Swift - Hiding TableViewHeader issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a collectionView in my tableView header. And if there is no data in collectionView I want to hide the tableView header.

I am getting random crashes on line self.tableView.tableViewHeader = nil
I tried changing the size of header (0.1) if data is empty and not setting the header is nil, but that didn't work.

And my app never crashes on my iphone or on simulator. But I am getting lots of crash reports from users via Crashlytics. And I can't

```
@IBOutlet weak var recView: UIView!   // --> my header

func loadRecData() {
  //Parse JSON here, 
  if //JSON data empty {
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
  }else {
     self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }           
}

func loadTableData() {}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  self.loadRec()
  self.loadTableData()
}
```

Crash report : https://www.dropbox.com/s/3y205d7g0fjaqid/crashReport.txt?dl=0

Comment: can you add the crash report also?

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3.0

Don't set `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil`, but set tableHeaderView height to zero in delegate method. it's work fine.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because first I want to load data inside header file and then set the header height. Delegate method called before I check the data in header. It always fails.